# Is there a way to download files automatically off of a (Egnyte) cloud drive link?

Tags: python, web-scraping, egnyte

We access the cloud drive through an Egnyte website link. The cloud website has an option to select or deselect which files to download, seen on the left of the picture. The "Download Files" button on the right is what downloads the files. I've had experience with web scraping before but never from cloud drives so any help would be appreciated. Would prefer to use python but am open to whichever language is best suited.[image]

We're the recipients of an FTP so using Egnyte's API won't work either.